# Rails 7 and tailwind css nav bar not loading correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I have a Rails 7 app. I have installed tailwind CSS and am trying to load a [sample nav bar](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/navbar/) But this is what I am seeing when I load the page:

[image]

I filled these instructions to install tailwind: https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/rails/

Where should I start looking?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser console?

Comment: No, no errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had not run `./bin/dev` locally. Once I did that everything worked.